# Add high-resolution bottom topography to Cartopy map

Tags: python, dictionary, cartopy, ocean, topography

I'm migrating from basemap to Cartopy and would like to plot ocean bottom topography with high resolution for a limited area.
In basemap I was using ETOPO1_Ice_g_gmt4.grd and transforming it to map coordinates based on documentation I had found somewhere. I don't know how to do that for Cartopy. Can anyone help?
Cheers, Sünnje

Update: Code in Basemap

map = Basemap(projection = 'merc', llcrnrlat = 67.2, urcrnrlat = 69.5,\
llcrnrlon = 8, urcrnrlon = 16.5, lat_ts = 67.5,)

```
topoFile = nc.NetCDFFile('/home/sunnje/data/ETOPO1_Ice_g_gmt4.grd','r')                                                       
topoLons = topoFile.variables['x'][:]                                                                                         
topoLats = topoFile.variables['y'][:]                                                                                         
topoZ = topoFile.variables['z'][:]                                                                                            
                                                                                                                              
# transform to nx x ny regularly spaced 1km native projection grid                                                            
nx = int((map.xmax - map.xmin)/1000.)+1                                                                                       
ny = int((map.ymax - map.ymin)/1000.)+1                                                                                       
                                                                                                                              
topodat = map.transform_scalar(topoZ,topoLons,topoLats,nx,ny)                                                                 
                                                                                                                              
tyi = np.linspace(map.ymin,map.ymax,topodat.shape[0])                                                                         
txi = np.linspace(map.xmin,map.xmax,topodat.shape[1])                                                                         
ttxi, ttyi = np.meshgrid(txi,tyi)                                                                                             
                                                                                                                              
cm = map.contour(ttxi, ttyi, topodat)
```

Comment: You should share your code that does it in Basemap, and ask for modifications to migrate to Cartopy.

Answer (score 1):

First, here is a demo code and its output map using cartopy. It uses the projection and map's extent that you specified.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal

# set extent necessary for data and plots
map_ext = [8, 16.5, 67.2, 69.5] #longmin,longmax,latmin,latmax

# for demo purposes
# set needed values for data creation
xmean, ymean = (map_ext[0]+map_ext[1])/2.0, (map_ext[2]+map_ext[3])/2.0
mu = np.array([xmean, ymean])
covar = np.array([[ 10. , -0.5], [-0.5,  10.5]])
lon_range = np.linspace(-180, 180, 200)
lat_range = np.linspace(-90, 90, 100)
xs,ys = np.meshgrid(lon_range, lat_range)
pos = np.empty(xs.shape + (2,))
pos[:, :, 0] = xs
pos[:, :, 1] = ys
# generate values as a function of (x,y) for contour genereation
zs = multivariate_normal(mu, covar).pdf(pos)

# setup projection for the map
projection = ccrs.Mercator(latitude_true_scale=67.5)
# create figure, axis for the map
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,6), subplot_kw={'projection': projection})

ax.set_extent(map_ext)
ax.coastlines()

ax.contourf(xs, ys, zs, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(), zorder=10, alpha=0.6)
ax.contour(xs, ys, zs, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(), zorder=12)

ax.gridlines(crs=ccrs.PlateCarree(), draw_labels=True)
plt.show()
```

[image: contour1]

To modify the code to plot your data, just change (xs,ys,zs) to (ttxi, ttyi, topodat).

Comment: Thank you very much, this is helpful.. What I still don't understand is how to transform the topographic data such that they get a shape that can be plotted with contourf. In Basemap I used the map.transform_scalar argument to generate that shape of the topodat. I'm unsure how I can do that now. Would you have an idea?

Comment: @Snj You better post that as a new question, more people will see and help. And the correct way of thanking is marking the `accept` button or voting up (when you have enough reputation).

Comment: @Snj You need to get 2 more reputation points to enable voting up/down questions and answers, and you will be able to comment in other people's Q/A also. FYI, accepting an answer to your question worths 2 points.